# Find ratio of lengths of BQ and AB?

Tags: geometry

ABCD is a rhombus. A stright line through $C$ cuts $AD$ produce at $P$ and $AB$ produced at $Q$. If $2DP=AB$ then ratio of lengths of $BQ$ and $AB$ ?

I got the answer  $1:2$

But if i do it in another way answer becomes $2:1$. i can not umderstand why? What i am doing is i am taking traingle BQC and  AQP and making them similar and using similar properties. but not getting right answer.

Please help

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is a bit unclear: I get that a straight line passing through the point C intersects the segment AD at the point P. Are you also saying there is a line passing through C that intersects the segment AB at point Q?  You can use my interpretation at the start of your question if it correctly reflects where P and Q are positioned.

Comment: yes sir it is the same line

Comment: Just as in a fraction, if trying to find the ratio $\frac x y$, and you obtain 2:1, then if trying to find the ratio $\frac yx$, we simply have 1:2.  So it depends on how you structure your ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Intercept Theorem we have that $\frac{AB}{BQ} = \frac{BQ - AQ}{BQ} = 1 - \frac{AQ}{BQ} = 1 - \frac{AP}{BQ} = 1 - \frac 12 = \frac 12$

Comment: so answer is 1:2 or 2:1 ? @stefan4024

Comment: It depends, what is the denominator and what the numerator. We have that $BQ:AB = 2:1$

Comment: but sir if i take tringle APQ and triangle ABD and make them similar because angle A is common in both triangles and Angle ADB = angle APQ and Angle ABD = angle AQP. and then AD/DP = AB/BQ. by this way i got BQ:AB = 1:2. please clear

Comment: I think you're wrong, as $APQ$ and $ABD$ aren't similar.

Comment: @NeerajSharma Note that my solution is when $P$ is between $A$ and $D$. In the case when $D$ is between $A$ and $P$ you will get the same result with the same reasoning,